# Using Find query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am new to Ruby on rails and i have a database using postgresql

I have tried using this command to find the value of radius column where user_id = current_user.id

```
UserPreference.find(current_user.id).radius
```

database table is set up like this

```
id   |  user_id  |  radius  |
901      899          10
902      900          20
903      901          30
```

with the query i am using:

suppose the user_id = 901

```
UserPreference.find(current_user.id).radius
```

this query gives me   10   I want it to give me    30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find by `user_id`:

```
UserPreference.find_by_user_id!(current_user.id).radius
```

or, even better, use [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

```
# user.rb:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_preference
  # ...
end

current_user.user_preference.radius
# => 30
```

Comment: thanks a million... Still learning ruby. it is a simplified language that i just need to learn. I am coming from php to ruby on rails. quite a difference

Answer (score 3):

Although not strictly deprecated, the new recommended way in Rails 4 is to use find_by with a hash. See  [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4e823b61190388219868744a34dcfe926bad511c/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L80)

So, this would make @Marek Lipka's first suggestion to be the following:

```
UserPreference.find_by!(user_id: current_user.id).radius
```